# Как выполнить crop выделенной части картинки с предварительно заданным размером (800*400)?

Tags: php, crop

Пытаюсь создать форму добавления поста с заданным размером картинки 800*400px.

800px постоянная ширина, 400px **максимальная высота** итоговой картинки, т.е. меньше 400 допустимо.

Минимально допустимый размер загружаемого в crop фото: 800х400

[Демонстрация](https://bemall.org/news/add/) того, что есть, поле "Выбрать изображение".

Сейчас можно загрузить изображение, выбрать место для crop и выполнить crop, но результат будет печальным, т.к. не сохраняются пропорции картинки.

Например, исходная картинка может быть размером 1920*1152px
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После crop выделенной части, результат получается таким
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне результат нужен именно такой, который выделен в редакторе crop с максимальными размерами 800*400 или 800 и меньше 400 в зависимости от исходной картинки, чтобы сохранялось пропорционально.

Данный редактор я подглядел на одном из сайтов, там в момент crop на сервер отправляется только 2 параметра, **url** картинки предварительно загруженной на сервер и параметр **y** - видимо начальная точка от левого, верхнего угла. Повторил тоже самое в [своем примере](https://bemall.org/news/add/).

Пример: `{"url":"https://site.ru/news/upload_tmp/files/file.jpg","y":"81"}`

Нашел аналогичный скрипт, перепробовал очень много вариантов настроек, но добиться результата не смог.

Вот код, который сейчас использую:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{

$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($postData, true);

$url = $data["url"];
$y = $data["y"];

$_POST['x1'] = '0';
$_POST['x2'] = '800';
$_POST['y'] = $y;
$_POST['y2'] = '400';
$_POST['img'] = $url;
$_POST['crop'] = 'files/';



/**
* Масштабирование изображения
*
* Функция работает с PNG, GIF и JPEG изображениями.
* Масштабирование возможно как с указаниями одной стороны, так и двух, в процентах или пикселях.
*
* @param string Расположение исходного файла
* @param string Расположение конечного файла
* @param integer Ширина конечного файла
* @param integer Высота конечного файла
* @param bool Размеры даны в пискелях или в процентах
* @return bool
*/

function resize($file_input, $file_output, $w_o, $h_o, $percent = false) {
list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($file_input);
if (!$w_i || !$h_i) {
    echo 'Невозможно получить длину и ширину изображения';
    return;
}
$types = array('','gif','jpeg','png');
$ext = $types[$type];
if ($ext) {
    $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext;
    $img = $func($file_input);
} else {
    echo 'Некорректный формат файла';
    return;
}
if ($percent) {
    $w_o *= $w_i / 100;
    $h_o *= $h_i / 100;
}
if (!$h_o) $h_o = $w_o/($w_i/$h_i);
if (!$w_o) $w_o = $h_o/($h_i/$w_i);
$img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o);
imagecopyresampled($img_o, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w_o, $h_o, $w_i, $h_i);
if ($type == 2) {
    imagejpeg($img_o,$file_output,100);
} else {
    $func = 'image'.$ext;
    $func($img_o,$file_output);
}
imagedestroy($img_o);
}

/**
* Обрезка изображения
*
* Функция работает с PNG, GIF и JPEG изображениями.
* Обрезка идёт как с указанием абсолютной длины, так и относительной (отрицательной).
*
* @param string Расположение исходного файла
* @param string Расположение конечного файла
* @param array Координаты обрезки
* @param bool Размеры даны в пискелях или в процентах
* @return bool
*/
function crop($file_input, $file_output, $crop = 'square',$percent = false) {
list($w_i, $h_i, $type) = getimagesize($file_input);
if (!$w_i || !$h_i) {
    echo 'Невозможно получить длину и ширину изображения';
    return;
}
$types = array('','gif','jpeg','png');
$ext = $types[$type];
if ($ext) {
    $func = 'imagecreatefrom'.$ext;
    $img = $func($file_input);
} else {
    echo 'Некорректный формат файла';
    return;
}
if ($crop == 'square') {
    $min = $w_i;
    if ($w_i > $h_i) $min = $h_i;
    $w_o = $h_o = $min;
} else {
    list($x_o, $y_o, $w_o, $h_o) = $crop;
    if ($percent) {
        $w_o *= $w_i / 100;
        $h_o *= $h_i / 100;
        $x_o *= $w_i / 100;
        $y_o *= $h_i / 100;
    }
    if ($w_o < 0) $w_o += $w_i;
    $w_o -= $x_o;
    if ($h_o < 0) $h_o += $h_i;
    $h_o -= $y_o;
}
$img_o = imagecreatetruecolor($w_o, $h_o);
imagecopy($img_o, $img, 0, 0, $x_o, $y_o, $w_o, $h_o);
if ($type == 2) {
    imagejpeg($img_o,$file_output,100);
    
} else {
    $func = 'image'.$ext;
    $func($img_o,$file_output);
}
imagedestroy($img_o);
}



function prov($per){
if (isset($per)) {
    $per = stripslashes($per);
    $per = htmlspecialchars($per);
    $per = addslashes($per);         
}
return $per;
}

if(isset($_POST)){
$filenew = 'main.png'; // перезаписываемый main.png

$x1 = prov($_POST['x1']);
$x2 = prov($_POST['x2']);
$y = prov($_POST['y']);
$y2 = prov($_POST['y2']);
$img = prov($_POST['img']);
$crop = prov($_POST['crop']);

crop($img, $crop.$filenew, array($x1, $y, $x2, $y2));   

//echo $filenew;
echo '{"result":"ok","data":"https:\/\/site.ru\/news\/cropImage\/files\/' . $filenew . '"}';

}

}else{
print '{"result":"error","message":"\u041f\u0440\u043e\u0438\u0437\u043e\u0448\u043b\u0430 \u043e\u0448\u0438\u0431\u043a\u0430 \u0432\u043e \u0432\u0440\u0435\u043c\u044f \u0441\u043e\u0445\u0440\u0430\u043d\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f"}';
}
```

По разному настраивал параметры по умолчанию (все кроме $url и $y), находил более-менее приличные варианты, но все не то :(

Возможно вы сталкивались с подобной задачей и сможете мне помочь разобраться в данном вопросе?

Спасибо!